# Overridden Event in Custom Control executes after Form Event

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I created a custom button in c#/WinForms that, among other things, gives the button a 3-D feel by altering the border thickness of the button in overridden MouseDown and MouseUp events using the following code in the overridden OnPaint event:

```
    public int BorderThickness { get; set; } = 3;
    public int ClickBorderThickness { get; set; } = 2;
    private MouseIsDown = false;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        int BorderWidth = (MouseIsDown) ? ClickBorderThickness : BorderThickness;

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(pevent.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
               SystemColors.ControlLightLight, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
               SystemColors.ControlLightLight, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
               SystemColors.ControlLightLight, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
               SystemColors.ControlLightLight, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset);

        //...Other Code...
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        MouseIsDown = true;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        MouseIsDown = false;
        Invalidate();
    }
```

I also created an overridden OnClick event:

```
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseIsDown = false;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
```

What I thought would happen is that the button would be redrawn and go back to its "unclicked" look prior to executing the code in the Click event for the button on my form.  That isn't what happened, and the overridden event was executed after ALL the code in the form Click event was completed.

How would I modify my custom button to execute the overridden Click event before the form Click event?

Comment: The sequence of events is (before and after calling base): MouseDown->Before - MouseDown->After, MouseUp->Before, MouseClick->Before, MouseClick->After, MouseUp->After. So the MouseClick method is called and completes before MouseUp returns after calling base. But the code in `MouseUp` before calling base is of course executed before `MouseClick`. `Invalidate()` instead enqueues a message that will be processed after the overridden methods return. Note that OnPaint is called anyway when you click a Button, so all Invalidate calls here add just one additional OnPaint call after MouseUp->After.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Jimi, I made the following change, which did the trick:

```
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseIsDown = false;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
```

(I moved the base.OnMouseUp(e) to the end in the OnMouseUp event).